# Jassor: Dissapear arrow first and last image

Tags: navigation, slider, jssor

I'm using the Jassor Slider, and everything looks good, I already quit the loop in the slider, but now I want to quit the arrow (left) in the first image and the other arrow (right) in the last image. Someone know how is this possible?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ParkEventHandler(slideIndex, fromIndex)
{
    if(slideIndex == 0)
    {
        $("#arrow_left").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("#arrow_right").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else if(slideIndex == jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount() - 1)
    {
        $("#arrow_left").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#arrow_right").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#arrow_left").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#arrow_right").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, ParkEventHandler);
```